# How to disable gnome-shell extension that overrides a system indicator

Tags: javascript, gnome-shell, gnome-3

On my system for some reason the brightness indicator would not work to change the brightness. Although xbacklight did work to change the brightness.

I wrote an extension to run xbacklight whenever it changes the brightness. It works. Although it does not disable (not that I need it to, but I would like to have good code). I am not sure how to properly disable the extension. Here is all the code.

```
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const Lang = imports.lang;
const Util = imports.misc.util;
const Brightness = imports.ui.status.brightness;

const BrightnessIndicator = new Lang.Class({
    Name : 'BrightnessIndicator',
    Extends : Brightness.Indicator,
    _sync : function () {
        let visible = this._proxy.Brightness >= 0;
        this._item.actor.visible = visible;
        if (visible) {
            this._slider.setValue(this._proxy.Brightness / 100.0);
        }
        let percent = this._proxy.Brightness.toString();
        Util.spawn(['xbacklight', '-set', percent]);
    }
});

function init() {
}

function enable() {
    var indicator = new BrightnessIndicator();
    Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._brightness = indicator;
}

function disable() {
    delete indicator;
    Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._brightness = null;
}
```

I have also tried adding a variable from enable() to hold the old _brightness and then reseting _brightness to that in the disable() code.

Neither approach has worked for me so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First place I always check for GS extension questions is code in GitHub. In this case BrightnessIndicator extends [panelMenu.SystemIndicator](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/panelMenu.js#L206) which doesn't offer you anything, so from there go up the inheritance until you find, for example, [ClutterActor.destroy()](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#ClutterActor-destroy). Then I guess just instantiate a new BrightnessIndicator just like how it's done in [panel.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/panel.js#L718).

One thing to note is that disable() is also called when the desktop is locked.